# ¿Como puedo sumar propiedades dentro de un mismo objeto y luego sumarlo a un array en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Mi duda es como puedo:

1. Sumar las propiedades de un objeto --pj: {id:1, valor:2, cantidad:3} --> 2 x 3 = 6
2. Luego de eso comparar si un objeto dentro del array es igual al id del anterior objeto pj--> {id:1, valor:2, cantidad:3}{id:1, valor:3, cantidad:4} --> true
3. Y si ese objeto es igual al anterior antes de sumarlo, tiene que primero hacer la cuenta de su valor y cantidad pj {categoria:"customer", valor:2, acumulado:3} {id:1, valor:3, acumulado:4} --> (2 x 3) + (3 x 4) = 18
4. Por ultimo el codigo tendria que tener los valores sumados de cada objeto y reducido a un solo objeto --> ejemplo {categoria:"customer", valorFinal: 24} y pushear al array

---

```
resultado final =  [{categoria: "customer", valorFinal=24}, {categoria: "company", valorFinal=15}]
```

---

hice este codigo con reduce pero no me esta saliendo

```js
const obj = [
    {
        categoria: 'customer',
        valor: 2,
        acumulado: 3,
    },
    {
        categoria: 'customer',
        valor: 2,
        acumulado: 3,
    },
    {
        categoria: 'customer',
        valor: 2,
        acumulado: 3,
    },
    {
        categoria: 'customer',
        valor: 2,
        acumulado: 3,
    },
    {
        categoria: 'company',
        valor: 5,
        acumulado: 3,
    },
]
const acumulador = (obj) => {
    let resultado = 0;

    const valores = obj.reduce((acumulador, valorActual) => {
        const elementoYaExiste = acumulador.find(elemento => elemento.categoria === valorActual.categoria);

        if (elementoYaExiste) {
            return acumulador.map(elemento => {
                if (elemento.categoria === valorActual.categoria) {
                    resultado = resultado += (elemento.valor * valorActual.acumulado);
                    console.log(resultado)
                    return{
                        ...elemento,
                        cantidad: resultado
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        return [...acumulador, valorActual];
    }, []);

    console.log(valores)

};

acumulador(obj)
```

Comment: En la pregunta hablas de `id` y de `cantidad` pero no veo esas propiedades en el código

Comment: Solo di como ejemplo, igualmente el codigo que envie tiene relacion en este caso id seria la categoria, lo voy a modificar.  Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer así (Codigo comentado):

```js
const obj = [{
    categoria: 'customer',
    valor: 2,
    acumulado: 3,
  },
  {
    categoria: 'customer',
    valor: 2,
    acumulado: 3,
  },
  {
    categoria: 'customer',
    valor: 2,
    acumulado: 3,
  },
  {
    categoria: 'customer',
    valor: 2,
    acumulado: 3,
  },
  {
    categoria: 'company',
    valor: 5,
    acumulado: 3,
  },
];

const result = Object.values(obj.reduce((acc, value) => {
  //El acumulador lo usas para crear un key:value de cada categoria para poder defniirla y en contrarla mas rapido
  //Revisas si esa categoria ya se definio, sino la defines
  acc[value.categoria] = acc[value.categoria] || { 
    categoria: value.categoria,
    valorFinal: 0
  };

  //Sumas el respectivo valor 
  acc[value.categoria].valorFinal += value.valor * value.acumulado;
  return acc; //retornas el nuevo acumulado
}, {}));
//Al finalizar usas Object.values para quitar los keys y dejar solo los valores

//mostramos el resultado
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Gracias pipe, me faltaba eso.